# Is there any way to get an iterator from bs4 findAll() like re.findIter()?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, iterator

I don't want for bs4 to parse the whole document but I also don't have any way to use the limit argument as I don't know how many links I would need to parse beforehand. If this were `re` I would use `re.finditer()` in this situation. But I couldn't find a similar function in bs4.

Comment: "I dont want for bs4 to parse the whole document" Is the document that long that this is actually the bottleneck of your code, or is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: Yes it is quite large and great suggestion though ive benchmarked

Comment: If it's not too big for the browser to display, it shouldn't be too big for Python.

Comment: Its an xml document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `BeautifulSoup` does not have a similar "iterative/lazy" version of `find_all()`.

One thing you can do in terms of not parsing the whole document is [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) which would at least allow you to focus `BeautifulSoup` on parsing the desired elements of a page only.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented that you deal with an XML document, you can use `ElementTree` whose elements implement [`.iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) (assuming you are using Python >= 3.2):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ['<root>'] + ['<a href="{}"/>' for i in range(10)] + ['</root>']
doc = ET.fromstring(''.join(doc))
print(doc.iter(tag='a'))
for link in doc.iter(tag='a'):
    print(link)
```

outputs

```
# <_elementtree._element_iterator object at 0x000001FFE8B44468>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFD05253B8>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8AF62C8>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B32B38>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B32B88>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B41228>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B451D8>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B45228>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B45278>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B452C8>
# <Element 'a' at 0x000001FFE8B45318>
```